# How can I ignore bodies while recording in wiremock

Tags: wiremock

I would like to record requests in such a way that the mappings end up with no *bodyPatterns* tag. In other words I want recorded mappings to be matched only based on path and regardless of body. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Although not exactly the removal of the tag, the contents of it can be influenced by setting the `extractBodyCriteria` to 1 byte. In the documentation on [Record and Playback](http://wiremock.org/docs/record-playback/#customising-your-recordings) there is also a java example:

```
  "extractBodyCriteria" : {
    "textSizeThreshold" : "1",
    "binarySizeThreshold" : "1"
  },
```

Comment: no this influences whether the response json is saved in the mapping json or in a separate file. I want the "request" body to be ignored

Comment: Thanks, was looking for a way to extract the response to separate file.